# Theme park visitor data

Tags: data-request, glam

Is there anywhere that I can obtain data on the numbers of visitors to attractions, such as museums, theme parks, etc.?  The most granular level I can seem to find is approximate figures per year, for example [here](http://www.aecom.com/deployedfiles/Internet/Capabilities/Economics/_documents/2012%20Theme%20Index%20Combined_1-1_online.pdf).  I would like something per month, week or even day if possible.

Note I am UK-based so would like to see something for UK attractions, though if anyone knows of anything for other locations then please do share!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No. The parks are not forthcoming with that information.

However, you will be able to come up with numbers on a circuitous methodology using maths.

Using the AECOM theme park visitor data you can break out the numbers based on seasonal and holiday volumes. Searching for seasonal jobs and other requirements you can get an initial idea of where the distributions for a daily or weekly level. The break out for individual attractions depends on luck; here in the states, specifically in Florida, we have a number of people doing person throughputs for each of the rides and based on this and the online posted wait times, allows to develop an individual attraction attendance amount.

Below is an example of the yearly distribution of individuals to the Walt Disney World Resorts in Orlando.

[image]